# How one can define inverse polylog function?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

I am not a matematician therefore word "define" can be wrong. I know that polylog function can be defined as series for argument $|z|<1$ and analytically continued for $|z|\geq 1$. My question: where I can find information about inverse polylogarithm function?